# Python Won't open Tkinter Askdirectory GUI

Tags: python, tkinter, directory, user-input

I am asking the user to select a folder so that I can create a list of all files in the selected folder and its subfolders. I have done this before with the code below in a separate file (works great).

However, copying the code below into a new file (same spot even - at the top of the code), the askdirectory GUI does not open. Visual Studio is indicating that it is running the code (I see Select Folder printed on the screen) but nothign below that appears to be "working".

I have attempted reboots of VS, Windows, killed Python.

Any suggestions?

```
from tkinter.filedialog import askdirectory
import sys, os

print("Select Folder")
MasterDirectory = askdirectory(title='Select Folder') # shows dialog box and return the path
print(MasterDirectory)
print("ISSUE HERE")
```

Comment: Are you sure that the popup window isn't bellow VS?

Comment: Can confirm that it is not appearing below VS.

Comment: This might be a sort of "Are you sure it's plugged in?" question, but you're creating a root instance of `tkinter.Tk()` and making sure to call `root.mainloop()` as usual, right? I'm only asking because it's not up there and I want to be sure.

Comment: try to run it without `VS` to check if problem can make `VS`. If you write all code then you don't need `VS` to run it. `VS` is needed only to develop code but not to run it when all code is ready.

Comment: @JRiggles totally understand if I was using TKINTER and creating a GUI. However in this instants I only require a directory. I know that Python and Tkinter are working as I can run a different script in the same folder location with the same code and it (the problematic code) works.

Comment: @furas i do not think this will help as the code works in a completely different script in the same folder location with the same code and it (the problematic code) works. Also Python NOOB here so would not know any other SW to try (other than Jupyter which does not work on my PC for some strange reason).

Comment: if code works without `VS` then problem can be `VS` and you can't change it - you can only run it without `VS`. And you don't need `VS` nor `Jupyter` to run it - simply run in console/terminal `python your_script.py `

Comment: @furas Did not know about this method of running python code. I redirected the CMD to the code location and entered the filename.py. I get the code running (IE it executes), no errors and nothing comes up.

Comment: Found something interesting, when I have "import pywinauto" or "from pywinauto.application import Application" higher in the code than the code stated above, the AskDirectory GUI will not open.

Comment: if moving `import pywinauto` can resolve your problem then you could put this as answer.